# "gcloud compute ssh" and "gcloud compute copy-files" return code propagation

Tags: command-line-interface, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'm trying to use these commands in a script but if they fail on the ssh or cp commands(e.g. file not found), I get a 0 return code from the gcloud command.

```
IT-MPB5471105-MBP:~ user$ gcloud compute --project myProject copy-files --zone us-central1-b /path/to/file/gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar hdfs@spark-test-m:/etl/hadoop
/path/to/file/gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar: No such file or directory
IT-MPB5471105-MBP:~ user$ echo $?
0
```

Is there a way to propagate the return code from the underlying scp, ssh command back as the return code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though `copy-files` does ignore the return code of `scp`. I've filed an internal feature request to propagate it correctly (`gcloud compute ssh` *does* pass through the return code).

In the meantime, you can use the `--dry-run` flag with `gcloud compute ssh` and `gcloud compute copy-files` to see the equivalent `scp`/`ssh` command lines, and call those directly.

Comment: Thanks, will use this, much appreciated.

Comment: This issue will be fixed in version 109.0.0, to be released in about a week.